# Why two lines in git source tree cross each other?

Tags: git, github

Why do these lines cross each other. They could have run parallel. What is the significance of crossing lines?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has no particular meaning in Git. This is merely how the GUI chose to visualize it.

You can see if Git does the same with `git log --graph --oneline`. My guess is that it won't show this crossing in that particular case, but hard to say without seeing the full screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please tell me one more thing. Why does git branch color changes from one commit to another sometimes. I have a linear history but i notice one part is shown in violet color and other in green. Why so even in linear?

Comment: Again, the colors don't have a particular meaning. I guess it has some heuristic which don't always coincide with the way you or I think in branches. See this question for screenshots where you observe the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot for answering